# A block falling on two intertwined springs

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, potential, spring

A cube with mass $m$ falls a distance $h$ straight on top of two intertwined springs (red and blue) with respective spring constants $k_1,k_2$ as the image below shows:

[image]

I'm asked to determine the maximum deformity of the springs. Here is my attempt:

The kinetic energy of the body when it touches the springs is $T_1 = mgh$ since all of the potential energy is converted to kinetic energy.

The work of the two springs from $0$ to $x_{max}$ should therefore be equal to $mgh.$

$$\int_0^{x_{max}}(k_1 x + k_2 x) dx = (k_1 + k_2)\int_0^{x_{max}}x dx = (k_1+k_2)(x_{max})^2/2.$$
So 
$$(k_1+k_2)(x_{max})^2/2 = mgh$$
$$x_{max} = \sqrt{\frac{2mgh}{(k_1+k_2)}}.$$

This is apparently wrong, the answer is supposed to be

$$x_{max} = \frac{mg}{(k_1+k_2)}\left(1 + \sqrt{1 + \frac{2h(k_1+k_2)}{mg}}\right)$$

Why is my answer wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity let's say $k_1 +k_2 = k$ . Now the spring is initially in its natural length . After the block strikes the spring it would come into SHM.  So let us find the mean position for the SHM. 
$$ k x_{mean} =mg$$

 So $x_{mean} = \frac{mg}{k}$

Now we will see the situation as a case of SHM.The velocity of the mass at $x_{mean}$ from the mean position is $\sqrt{2gh}$.
Now we apply $v^2 =W^2 (A^2 -x^2)$
$2gh = \frac{k}{m} ( A^2- \frac{(mg)^2}{k^2})$

 From here we get $A^2 =\frac{2mgh}{k} + \frac{(mg)^2}{k^2}$

 So this is the amplitude of the motion . Therefore the block will move down by a further A distance from the mean position.

 Hence total compression in the spring would be 
$$x_{mean} +A$$ 
This simplifies to your answer.

Comment: This does not answer my question "Why is my answer wrong?". This just gives a possibly correct answer (which doesn't correspond to the answer in my book). It doesn't help me.

Comment: Because you did not consider loss in gpe of block as it moves down the spring. Do it you will get a quadratic in x . Again solving it will give the correct answer

Comment: Moreover my answer simplifies to that in your book.